# Setting bar value in d3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I am trying to set the quantity value inside of each individual bar in my bar graph like the image I have provided below:

[image: Wanted]

Unfortunately, the code I have tried hovers the percentage in a really weird spot and I'm not sure what I can do to achieve the desired effect.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import './BarChart.css';

const dataSet = [
    { category: '1', quantity: 15 },
    { category: '2', quantity: 10 },
    { category: '3', quantity: 50 },
    { category: '4', quantity: 30 },
    { category: '4', quantity: 75 },
    { category: '5', quantity: 5 }
];

const BarChartTest = () => {
    const d3Chart = useRef();
    const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight
    });
    const update = useRef(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Listen for any resize event update
        window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
            setDimensions({
                width: window.innerWidth,
                height: window.innerHeight
            });

            // if resize, remove the previous chart
            if (update.current) {
                d3.selectAll('g').remove();
            } else {
                update.current = true;
            }
        });

        DrawChart(dataSet, dimensions);
    }, [dimensions]);

    const margin = { top: 50, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60 };

    const DrawChart = (data, dimensions) => {
        const chartWidth = parseInt(d3.select('#d3RenewalChart').style('width')) - margin.left - margin.right;
        const chartHeight = parseInt(d3.select('#d3RenewalChart').style('height')) - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        const colors = ['#7fc97f', '#beaed4', '#fdc086', '#ffff99', '#386cb0', '#f0027f', '#bf5b17', '#666666'];

        const svg = d3
            .select(d3Chart.current)
            .attr('width', chartWidth + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr('height', chartHeight + margin.top + margin.bottom);
        const x = d3
            .scaleBand()
            .domain(d3.range(data.length))
            .range([margin.left, chartWidth + margin.right])
            .padding(0.1);

        svg.append('g')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + chartHeight + ')')
            .call(
                d3
                    .axisBottom(x)
                    .tickFormat((i) => data[i].category)
                    .tickSizeOuter(0)
            );

        const max = d3.max(data, function (d) {
            return d.quantity;
        });

        const y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 100]).range([chartHeight, margin.top]);

        svg.append('g')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',0)')
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickFormat((d) => d + '%'));

        svg.append('g')
            .attr('fill', function (d, i, j) {
                return colors[i];
            })
            .selectAll('rect')
            .data(data)
            .join('rect')
            .attr('x', (d, i) => x(i))
            .attr('y', (d) => y(d.quantity))
            .attr('height', (d) => y(0) - y(d.quantity))
            .attr('width', x.bandwidth())
            .attr('fill', function (d, i) {
                return colors[i];
            })
            .append('text')
            .text(function (d) {
                return d.quantity;
            })
            .on('click', (d) => {
                location.replace('https://www.google.com');
            });

        svg.selectAll('.text')
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append('text')
            // .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
            .attr('fill', 'green')
            .attr('class', 'label')
            .attr('x', function (d) {
                return x(d.quantity);
            })
            .attr('y', function (d) {
                return y(d.quantity) - 20;
            })
            .attr('dy', '0')
            .text(function (d) {
                return d.quantity + '%';
            })
            .attr('x', function (d, i) {
                console.log(i * (chartWidth / data.length));
                return i * (chartWidth / data.length);
            })
            .attr('y', function (d) {
                console.log(chartHeight - d.quantity * 4);
                return chartHeight - d.quantity * 4;
            });
    };

    return (
        <div id="d3RenewalChart">
            <svg ref={d3Chart}></svg>
        </div>
    );
};

export default BarChartTest;
```

Here is a link to my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-sun-kri6m?file=/src/BarChart.css).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Codesandbox provided didn't contain any React code.

Copy-pasting the above into the component code and calling it from `App.js` revealed that resizing the window would cause problems, because the line `svg.selectAll(".text")` was having a fresh copy appended with every render (re-size).

[Here is the original code in a working Codesandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-dream-lzbh3?file=/src/BarChartTest.js:2967-2996)

[image]

**[A refactored version of that code is in this updated Codesandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-frost-nmqc9?file=/src/BarChartTest.js:2547-3080)**

**Solution:**

In addition to the `.append()` call appending the `.text` element to the `svg` without being removed, the code above appears to set the `x` and `y` attributes with `.attr()` twice; removing the additional code and changing a few values made it possible to position the bar labels in what is presumably the correct position.

[image: d3 bar label positioning]

[image: d3 bar label positioning]

Here's a refactored version:

```
// create labels
    svg
      .append("g")
      .attr("fill", "black")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .style("font", "24px sans-serif")
      .selectAll("text")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr("class", "label");

// position labels
    svg
      .selectAll(".label")
      .data(data)
      .attr("x", (d, index) => x(index) + x.bandwidth() / 2 + 24)
      .text((d) => d.quantity + "%")
// to exclude the animation, remove these two lines
      .transition()
      .delay((d, i) => i * 20)
//
      .attr("y", (d) => y(d.quantity) + 22);
```

On another note, a color with higher contrast is advised here. White text on lighter backgrounds may not be visible and won't provide an accessible experience for everyone. [**Here's the refactored Codesandbox again.**](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-frost-nmqc9?file=/src/BarChartTest.js:2547-3080)

Hope this was helpful! ✌️